# Proof problem, 5 people in a square room, prove that at most they are 4√2 ft away from each other

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

"There are 5 people are in a square room that has dimensions of 8ft by 8ft.  Assume that these people are just points.  Prove that among these people, there is a pair that is standing at most 4√2 ft away from each other."

I don't understand how to prove this. Wouldn't a pair be standing at 8√2 from each other? Given if 2 people were in the corners?

Or, if say I put 2 people in the top left and bottom left corner, and the other 3 people on the far right, the pair in the corners would still be 8ft from each other?

Wouldn't this only work if 4 people were in the corners and one in the middle?

Comment: Looks like a sphere packing problem. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square

Comment: If you place the two people in the corners where will you place the rest of the five people? The problem states "there is a pair that is standing at most 4√2 ft away from each other.", referring to any pair.

Answer (score 4):

Divide the square into four subsquares(connect the middle points of the sides of the big square) then by the pigeonhole principle(4 small squares 5 people) there is one square that contains two people. But now the biggest distance they can be away from each other is clearly the length of the diagonal of the smaller square which is $\frac{8}{2}\sqrt{2}$ as desired. 
You only need to prove that there are 2 people at most this distance away from each other, the statement clearly does not hold for all pairs of people as your example with the two points in the corners of the big square shows.